# how to install lua liberec on mac os?

Tags: macos, lua

how to install lua liberec on mac os?

I do not know how to do this

main.lua

```
local luajson = require "lunajson"

local file = io.open("main.json", "r")
local data = file:read("*all")
file:close()

local tbl = luajson.decode(data)
print(tbl["name"])
```

main.json

```
{
    "name": "Timofey"
}
```

terminal:

```
lua: main.lua:1: module 'lunajson' not found:
    no field package.preload['lunajson']
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.4/lunajson.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.4/lunajson/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.4/lunajson.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.4/lunajson/init.lua'
    no file './lunajson.lua'
    no file './lunajson/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.4/lunajson.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.4/loadall.so'
    no file './lunajson.so'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    main.lua:1: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

I tried restarting the mac, but it still gives an error

Answer (score 1):

Use luarocks.

1. Install brew ( https://brew.sh/ )
2. Install luarocks:

brew install luarocks

3. Install your library:

luarocks install love2d

done